# How do I return a reference to a part of a recursive data structure?

Tags: data-structures, rust

I'm trying to define a recursive data structure in Rust, but there are some pieces missing in my understanding of Rust and memory - the only thing that I manage to do is pick a fight with the borrow checker.

I have the following stub of a quad tree and want to project one of the quadrants as follows.

```
use CC::{Node, Leaf};

enum CC {
    Node(i32, bool, i32, Rc<CC>, Rc<CC>, Rc<CC>, Rc<CC>),
    Leaf(bool),
}

impl CC {
    fn nw(&self) -> CC {
        match *self {
            Node(_, _, _, ref nw, _, _, _) => *nw.clone(),
            _ => panic!()
        }
    }
}
```

But all I end up with is

```
src/hashlife.rs:34:47: 34:58 error: cannot move out of borrowed content
src/hashlife.rs:34             Node(_, _, _, ref nw, _, _, _) => *nw.clone(),
                                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Do you want to return a `CC` that is distinct from the one in your tree, or a reference to the same one? Your return type of `nw` indicates it would be the former.

Comment: I want to return a reference to the same node present in the tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options here.

First, you can return a reference to the subtree:

```
fn nw(&self) -> &CC {
    match *self {
        Node(_, _, _, ref nw, _, _, _) => &**nw,
        _ => panic!()
    }
}
```

Second, you can return a reference-counted pointer:

```
fn nw(&self) -> Rc<CC> {
    match *self {
        Node(_, _, _, ref nw, _, _, _) => nw.clone()
        _ => panic!()
    }
}
```

You can't return just `CC`, however, unless you are willing to clone the value itself. The reason is that this would mean moving out of `Rc`, leaving it in some undefined state, which is rightly prohibited.

Comment: I think for the first case, you can now just say `Node(_, _, _, ref nw, _, _, _) => nw`, due to more flexible coercions.

Comment: Thanks! Of course it makes sense to return Rc<CC> instead of CC.